# TFRecord feature has wrong value

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am trying to train some embeddings and am putting my dataset into tfrecord form. When I write one example to the file like so:

```
tf_features = {
        'given': int64_feature(given),
        'context': bytes_feature(np.array(context).tostring())
}
writer.write(tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=tf_features)).SerializeToString())
```

where `int64_feature` and `bytes_feature` are defines as:

```
def bytes_feature(val):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[val]))

def int64_feature(val):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[val]))
```

and I print out an example (given, context) pair, I get something like: `(698, [686, 439, 464, 775])` which is fine.

However, when I try to read from the same file like so:

```
def parse_example(w, tf_example):
    feats_dict = {
        'given': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=0),
        'context': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }
    features = tf.parse_single_example(tf_example, feats_dict)
    context = tf.decode_raw(features['context'], tf.int64)

    context_feats = dict()
    ctx_idx = 0
    for i in range(w):
        if i == w//2: continue
        context_feats['context%d' % ctx_idx] = context[ctx_idx]
        ctx_idx += 1

    return context_feats, features['given']

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([fname]).map(partial(parse_example, 5))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    iter_features, iter_labels = iterator.get_next()
    features = sess.run(iter_features)
    labels = sess.run(iter_labels)
    print(features, labels)
```

For the same context pair as before, I get `(464, [686, 439, 464, 775])`. The given label is always the third from the context labels.

I've been staring at this code for hours but am stumped. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Why exactly do you need for loop in parse function?

Comment: I don't per se but when I use it as part of an input_fn to a tensorflow Estimator, it is helpful to have each context label with its own key to create separate feature columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think figured out what was going on and it is a fairly silly mistake. In the following lines:

```
iter_features, iter_labels = iterator.get_next()
features = sess.run(iter_features)
labels = sess.run(iter_labels)
```

I am running `sess.run` twice and because of the behavior of the iterator, when I was getting the features, it was returning the correct features, but when I was getting the labels, it was returning the labels of the NEXT example.

It makes sense that the label I was getting was always the third in the context because of the sliding window used to get the given-context pairs.

I changed the aforementioned lines to:

```
iter_ex = iterator.get_next()
ex = sess.run(iter_ex)
print(ex)
```

And it runs as expected.